# Website not able to scroll towards the left side of the Page while the windows is small

Tags: html, css

Hi Guys I have this website: http://www.godfreysammut.com. As you can see in the image attached when the window is reduced in height, I am not able to scroll towards the left.

[image: Scroll Problem, as you can see I cannot scroll further on the left.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you're positioning your `#wrapper` div absolutely; you don't need to. Since you know the width of the `#wrapper` div, you can center it like this...

```
div#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto; /* this will center the element */
    position: relative;
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work... it should. I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: @Hristo WoW great answer, why was I complicating it so much :(. So Margin: auto; will automatically center the page in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, I researched about it, and it does, thanks mate, I was doing wrong all the time :)

Comment: @Ryan... sorry for the delay, I was ordering some pizza :) yes, if you know how wide your element will be, then the browser will automatically center it if you do `margin: auto`. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Ryan... by the way, Stack Overflow tradition shows that the most helpful answer is usually marked as "Accepted". So whichever of these (currently) 3 answers is most helpful, you should accept.

Comment: @Hristo - Yes mate I know that, but I could not chose it as the best answer, it was telling me I had to wait my time, I guess there's some default time limit which has to pass :) Thanks a lot, your solution will help me a lot in future

Comment: @Hristo - there is just one last thing, is that compatible with all browsers, even IE6?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not 100% sure. I think it should be but I can't say for certain. I'm going to say yes but do let me know if I'm wrong :) In regards to IE 6, I would recommend to avoid making things work on IE 6 since Microsoft is shutting it down... http://ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 2):

The problems seems to be with your `div#wrapper`.

**Remove** the following from your `css`:

```
position:absolute;    
left:50%;
margin-left:480px;
```

and **replace** with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another technique to center your site than `position: absolute` with a negative `margin-left`.

- On `#wrapper`, remove `position: absolute`, `margin-left: -480px`, `top: 0`.
- On `#wrapper`, add `margin: 0 auto`.

`position: relative` on `#wrapper` is much easier, fail:

<strike>Now there's a bunch of other stuff to fix.. the other answers don't  seem to mention this :)</strike>

- on `#top ul`, add `position: relative` and `margin: -12px 0 0 0`.
- On `div#main`, change `position: absolute` into `position: relative`.

Testing only in Firefox, that's almost pixel perfect the same as it was, but with your issue fixed.

Comment: Before you had `position: relative` (was `position: absolute` at the start, which I disabled in Firebug as part of testing my answer) on `#wrapper`, they were misplaced. I kinda rushed my answer after seeing the first one was posted - adding `position: relative` is an easier way to accomplish those last two bullet points I wrote. In other words, @Hristo answered it faster and better.